# Adding a list of numbers with a sentinel C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, sum

Hi I am supposed to write a program that asks the user to list all their calories, and enter 0 to finish. This is my code so far. My code isn't working and when I test it, it lists all the numbers correctly, but they don't add up and it just display: "The total calories are:" but they don't add up.

```
    float calories;
    float total = 0;
    cout << "Enter the list of numbers of your calories. Then enter 0 to finish:\n";
    while (calories!=0){
        cin >> calories;
        total+=calories;
    }
    cout << "The total calories are:";
    cin >> total;
```

Comment: Use `cout << total` instead of `cin >> total`. You want to show the result, not to ask the user for it.

Comment: that doesn't work. @zdf

Comment: 1. `calories` is indeterminate on first entry to `while (calories!=0)`. 2. What @zdf said is clearly a problem; `cin >> total;` will obviously not work for sending `total` to *output*; that should be `cout << total << '\n';` (newline added to promote a line flush).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
float calories = -1; // Initialize this with a nonzero value
float total = 0;
cout << "Enter the list of numbers of your calories. Then enter 0 to finish:\n";
while (calories!=0){
    cin >> calories;
    total+=calories;
}
cout << "The total calories are: " << total << '\n';
```

If you don't initialize calories explicitly, your loop may not start. Many compilers will implicitly initialize scalar variables to 0, but in any case you should definitely initialize the variable before you test it.

Comment: If you don't initialize `calories` explicitly, your loop may not start. Many compilers will implicitly initialize scalar variables to 0, but in any case you should definitely initialize the variable before you test it.

Comment: you should move the comment in the actual answer.

Comment: @zdf Right. Done. Thx.

Comment: "Many compilers will implicitly initialize scalar variables to 0" might be true in debug builds but in general reading from uninitialized variables is UB

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Reading uninitialized variables is always UB. In this case, the loop would work correctly for the wrong reason if `calories` is uninitialized but starts off with a nonzero value.

Comment: my misunderstanding. I though that sentence explains why OPs code is wrong, but it rather explains why OP might not be as lucky as they were. We agree that it is wrong anyhow ("...but in any case..")